# Using ZendPdf in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to wrap my head around zend framework 2 and it's module system.  I have the the skeleton application in the Getting Started guide working.  I now want to use ZendPdf to load in an existing pdf file and work with it.  I've done the following so far:

- downloaded and installed ZendPdf using composer to my skeleton app
- Added ZendPdf to my application_config.php
- Added a simple controller action to create a new ZendPdf class and load in a document
- I also created a view for the controller action.

When ever I call the action in the controller I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (ZendPdf) could not be initialized
```

Obviously, from the error, I need to add zendpdf to the module_config.php so the ModuleManager can pick it up.  This is were I get lost.  I don't know how to configure zendpdf in the config file.  This is what I have so far:

**module.config** in the Album Module

```
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
    ),
),
// Routes for 
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
'zendpdf' => array() /* what to do here */
);
```

This is the controller action in my **AlbumController**

```
public function viewPdfAction()
{
  $pdf = ZendPdf::load('/tmp/pdf_report.pdf');
}
```

This is the **application.config**

```
<?php
   return array(
     'modules' => array(
       'Application',
       'Album',
       'AlbumRest',
       'ZendPdf'
     ),
     'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
     ),
      'module_paths' => array(
          './module',
          './vendor',
     ),
  ),
);
```

I've been reading the docs but am just not getting it.  I need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using clues from Andy this is what I found that worked.

Install ZendPdf via composer.  Using composer will make ZF2 automatically auto-the library.  below is the composer.json file that I used

```
{
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
      }
    ],
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
        "zendframework/zendpdf": "*"
    }
}
```

In your controller import the ZendPdf namespace

```
use ZendPdf\PdfDocument;
```

Then somewhere in a Controller action create a new pdf object and work with it

```
public funciton someAction()
{
     $pdf = PdfDocument::load('path/to/pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you are using is [this](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf)? In that case, it is not a module, but a *library*, which would explain why you are not able to load it as a module. If you installed it with Composer, then you should be able to find it within your `vendor` directory, and it should be autoloaded. You should then be able to use it like you use all of the classes within Zend Framework by using the appropriate namespace. I have not used this myself, but I think this is what you did wrong.

Comment: Yes, the link you provided is exactly what I'm trying to use.  I installed it with composer and it is in the vendor directory.  You mentioned using it with the proper namespace.  What would that be?
`
use ZendPdf
`

Comment: Try this: `$pdf = \ZendPdf::load('/tmp/pdf_report.pdf');`. Or you can add the namespace above your class definition: `use ZendPdf;` and then do like you did in your action.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Of course it has to be `\ZendPdf\PdfDocument::load('/tmp/pdf_report.pdf');` and `use ZendPdf\PdfDocument`.